# PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: html, parsing, dom

Help with parsing DOM tree
is following tree

```html
<div itemprop="description" property="v:description">
<span class="gray">type:</span>  
   black  
   <br>  
 <span class="gray">type2:</span>
  pack 
  <br>
</div>
```

We must all draw the archive of the form

```
$data = ['type:' => 'black',  .....]
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you're asking. Could you please rephrase and show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/EA4Nn3Es8q5Vmb

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image you added in the comment, I suppose you'd want something like this:

```
<div itemprop="description" property="v:description">
    <?php
        $data = ['type' => 'black',  'type2' => 'pack'];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    ?>
    <span class="gray"><?php echo $key; ?>:</span>  
        <?php echo $value; ?>
        <br />  
    <?php 
         } 
    ?>
</div>
```